# Price of my project in Google Big Query pricing

Tags: google-bigquery, price

I am little confused about pricing of Google Big Query. I need to get final price of my project in Google Big Query. So, how much will cost 1 month of using Big Query if the project will need:

- 10GB of new data will be added each day
- There will be made 25 millions inserts each day to given table - each insert size will be 0.4KB.
- Each day there will be 1000 queries fired through whole current table of stored data.
- All data will be collected (without deletion) for a 1 year.

Comment: what exactly you are confused about? did you have chance to see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing? have you tried some calculation and got something unreasonable? show us your work so we can help you with the confusion :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the information you provided I’m guessing you’ll need to use Streaming inserts as normal uploads to BigQuery datasets have 2 daily [limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) (Daily destination table update limit — 1,000 updates per table per day and Load jobs per project per day — 50,000 (including failures)) that would be hard to workaround.

The price of your project  will be composed from the 3 parts: storage, streaming inserts and queries.

**BigQuery Storage**

> For the first month you’ll pay $0.0067 per day for each lot of 10GB ($0.02(per GB per month) * 10(GB) * 1/30(months)).  So for 30 days the total cost will be about **4 USD** (estimated for daily added lots of 10GB). For the next 11 months it will costs you 0.02 * 300GB * 11 months = **66 USD**.

If a table is not edited for 90 consecutive days, the price of storage for that table automatically drops by 50 percent to $0.01 per GB per month. Also, if you don’t access the data you can transfer it to a bucket and chose the [storage class](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#comparison_of_storage_classes) - Nearline Storage and it will cost you 0.01$ per 1GB resulting in a cost of 11 months * 300GB * 0.01 = 33 USD.

**Streaming inserts**

> The cost for the streaming inserts for daily 25.000.000 inserts of 1KB (1 KB is the minimum size per individual row) → 25GB (per day) → 750GB (in the month)
>   Total price per month: **37.5 USD** (750GB * $0.05 (per GB successfully inserted))

**Query price**

> I roughly estimated that each query would require 1G of data to be processed resulting in a 1TB per day (1000 queries * 1G) so it will cost 5$/day → **150 USD** per month.
>   As this is the most expensive part of your project you should correctly [estimate](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/estimate-costs) it. I’d advise you to run some tests with provisioned queries, maybe using the [public datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/stackoverflow) and see how much it will cost. Also keep in mind about this [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs) to limit the queries costs.

Total cost is 4 + 66 + 37.5 + 150 = **257.5 USD** not far from the estimated price given by the [BigQuery pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) - $255.40

- As it’s an estimate I excluded from calculations the free quotas of 10 GB/month free storage and 1TB/month for queries.

Comment: As there will be only inserts - then "updates per table per day" and "load jobs per project" is not what i'll need, so i think i don't need to worry about that 2 limits at all. In conclusion - thanks for all explanations above, now it's more clear to me!